# The edit box should not scroll when I format a code block

Tags: bug, google-chrome

Whenever I highlight code and format it, the text box scrolls back to the beginning. This is quite annoying on longer posts where I am formatting something towards the middle of the post, as I have to find my location again.

[image: Reproduction]

I see this behavior here on Meta, on Stack Overflow Main, and Meta Stack Exchange.

I am using Chrome on OS X

1. Version 41.0.2272.89 (64-bit)
2. Version 42.0.2283.5 **canary** (64-bit)
3. Version 43.0.2318.2 **canary** (64-bit)

Comment: Unable to reproduce, either here or at [so], using Firefox 35.0. (Not voting either way; just adding information.)

Comment: Unable to reproduce either, running Firefox on Windows 7.

Comment: I've previously been able to reproduce this (sporadically) on Chrome/Ubuntu. Right now I can't reproduce it at all.

Comment: I can't reproduce this when editing an answer here on Meta using Chrome Version 41.0.2272.89 m (64-bit) on Windows 8.1, nor in a question on Main, if that helps any...

Answer (score 1):

I am unable to reproduce this on the latest stable versions of Safari, Chrome, and Firefox on OS X. It's probably a bug in the Canary build, so it should be fixed eventually.

Note that [Stack Exchange does not support beta versions of browsers](https://meta.stackexchange.com/questions/56161/which-browsers-are-officially-supported-and-what-else-do-i-need), and while it may be an inconvenience, using stable versions will obviously give you the best results.

Comment: I'm down with not supporting beta browsers, but I just realized it also happens at work, where I am using a stable version of Chrome.